# DPC latency caused by NIC

Tags: audio, intel, nic

I have audio crackling and stuttering for a few days now. I don't know why it started doing that. It's really annoying because even dragging a window around makes the sound stutter and watching a 4K video is almost impossible. 
I believe the problem comes from my NIC, Intel 82579V. I downloaded DPC Latendy Checker and when I start downloading at a few mbps (torrent) I have a DPC latency of around 8000 to 16000µs. Doesn't matter if it's 3mbps or 600mbps. When I disable the NIC or stop all network traffic I'm back to 1000µs.
I tried reinstalling the drivers by uninstalling and letting Windows reinstall. 
Any idea how to fix this ?
It does it with onboard audio and through nVidia display port audio.
Specs : Intel i7 3770k @4.2GHz, Z77A-GD55, GTX 780. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple avenues you can take:

- Contact the system/board manufacturer or PC supplier.
- Post the issue on communities.intel.com Wired Ethernet blog.

  - https://communities.intel.com/community/wired

There might be others already seeing the same issue and complaining about it in the same ways listed above.